# Why is my sink not draining well?

Tags: drain, sink

The rate at which water is removed from a bathroom sink has significantly declined.  The p-trap was removed and a bucket placed underneath to catch water.  The sink was filled and water was released into the bucket: the result is that rate at which the water flowed into the bucket was unchanged (very slow).  This test indicates that the bottleneck is in the piping before the p-trap.  P-trap was clean \ unobstructed.

What is the most common cause for this issue?  What is the next step for diagnosing corrective action?

[image]

Comment: If your sink has a pop-up plug there may be stuff built up around the mechanism which raised/lowers it.

Comment: Hair and drains do not get along. They need to be cleaned occasionally especially if you have people with long hair in the house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the pop-up drain - some just need a quarter-turn to disengage, some you have to fuss with the rod that pops them up, some can be either way (and end up as quarter-turn when I put them back together - I suppose the other way is for making them harder to steal in public bathrooms.)

There is probably a (revolting, sorry, them's the breaks of plumbing) mass of hair and glop hung up in the stopper. I typically need to do this every year or so to our main bathroom sink as hair does get in there, and there's a point where trying to prevent that completely is more work than just cleaning it out when needed.

You may want rubber gloves, depending on your personal tolerance for revolting drain glop.

Comment: You nailed-it: Rubber Gloves are key: also used an old toothbrush to clean the inside.  I fussed with the pop-up rod to remove the stopper.  Removing the p-trap enabled verification that the hair was obstructing waterflow.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is usually hair, and stuff trapped by the hair.  On many sinks, trying to remove the drain plug is a royal pain in the butt.  On shower drains, it can be a problem getting deep and around bends.  Tools that just loosen and push the debris can result in it lodging somewhere harder to reach.

There's a clever tool that usually works for me without needing to disassemble anything.  There are versions of it widely available.  Here's one at Home Depot called ["Zip-It Bath and Sink Hair Snare":](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Zip-It-Bath-and-Sink-Hair-Snare-BC00400/100665735)

[image]

It's the best couple of bucks I ever spent and it's saved me endless amounts of time.  It's a thin, flexible strip that slides through the gaps in the underside of the drain plug.  It has barbs that snag the hair.  You just work your way around the gaps, pushing the tool down the drain, pulling it back out, and removing the hair and crud it pulls out with it.  They're generally made of plastic but they're tough.  I've had one for well over a decade and it still works like new (and they're easy to clean up).

Comment: Great tool. It goes a long ways in when needed.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed—once I managed to find one. Annoyingly, there doesn’t seem to be a standard term for these things, some of the ones I saw were "plastic hair snake", "flexible drain stick", "drain hair removal tool", and variations thereof. Thanks for the tip!